# Too many re-renders. How can it happen on this code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just starting with React, and was trying to practice by creating a simple page with a button that show the Modal component when clicked... But I'm running into a *Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.* and I stucked there, I can't find what's wrong.

Can someone please help me?

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import View from './View'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <View />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

View.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal.js';

const View = () => {
    let [showModal, setModal] = React.useState(false)
    return(
        <>
            {showModal ?? <Modal />}
            <button onClick={setModal(!showModal)}>
                Mostrar modal
            </button>
        </>
    )
}

export default View;
```

Modal.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Modal = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Modal</h1>
            <p>Mostrando o modal</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modal;
```

Comment: You need to pass a **function** to `onClick` and not the return value of `setModal(!showModal)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally invoke the state change (triggering a render recursively) when trying to pass your `onClick` handler here (instead passing the return value of the function invocation):

```
<button onClick={setModal(!showModal)}>
```

Instead, pass a function that can get invoked on click:

```
<button onClick={() => setModal(!showModal)}>
```